# Stuck with laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to write a filter system using laravel, here is the situation:

Here is my `$inputs` array. Colors are checkboxes, and material is a dropdown :

```
$inputs = [
    'colors' => ['green' => 'green', 'red' => 'red'],
    'material' => 'wood',
]
```

Here is the table (`variants_values`) I'm looking at. This is where I stock all combination of properties for my variants :

```
id  | product_id | variant_id | property_id |   label   | value
550           91          213             1    color      green
551           91          213             2    material   wood
552           91          214             1    color      red
552           91          214             2    material   plastic
```

Here is my request. The goal is to return corresponding products, so I use a `whereHas()` method to make a subquery over my `variants_values`:

```
    foreach($inputs as $key => $input) {
        $products->whereHas('variants_values', function($query) use($key, $input) {
            if(is_array($input)) {
                $query->where('label', $key)->whereIn('value', $input);
            } elseif(!empty($input)) {
                $query->where('label', $key)->where('value', $input);
            }

        });
    }
```

This code works quite well except one situation:

- If I check `green` color and `wood`material, I want that my product `91` is returned, which is the case.

BUT

- If I check `red` color and `wood` material, I want no results because the `red` variant is made of `plastic`, not `wood`.

Actually, the product `91` is still returned because actually, my code don't check if it's the same variant that correspond to the `$inputs`;

So I need something in my code that would say :

```
foreach($inputs as $key => $input) {
    $products->whereHas('variants_values', function($query) use($key, $input) {
        if(is_array($input)) {
            $query->where('label', $key)->whereIn('value', $input);
        } elseif(!empty($input)) {
            $query->where('label', $key)->where('value', $input);
        }
        ##
        $query->where('Verify that the variant ID is the same or something like that');
        ##
    });
}
```

I know I'm not far from the solution but I'm stuck here actually.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this requires a more complex query.

Put this in your `Product` model:

```
public function variants() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'variants_values');
}
```

Copy the `variants_values` relationship to your `Variant` model.

Then try this:

```
$products->whereHas('variants', function($query) use($inputs) {
    foreach($inputs as $key => $input) {
        $query->whereHas('variants_values', function($query) use($key, $input) {
            $query->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id');
            if(is_array($input)) {
                $query->where('label', $key)->whereIn('value', $input);
            } elseif(!empty($input)) {
                $query->where('label', $key)->where('value', $input);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your request perfectly works. I just edited it cause I need to check the variant_id in the ->whereColumn() method, but the logic was great.

Comment: It should be `$query->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id');`. If I change it to your suggestion, it doesn't work anymore.